# how to split a javascript returned String object in java

Tags: java, parsing, split

I have a string array of objects which I pulled from javascript into java as a single string . It looks like this .

```
[
   {"sourcevalue":"KRISHNA@IN.IBM.COM","userIdValue":"Krishna L Pappu - 
    krishnalakshmi","objectId":"A1001001A20E08A74322C03420"},
   {"sourcevalue":"KRISHNA@IN.IBM.COM","userIdValue":"Krishna L Pappu - 
    krishnalakshmi","objectId":"A1001001A20E08A74322C03420"},
   {"sourcevalue":"KRISHNA@IN.IBM.COM","userIdValue":"Krishna L Pappu - 
    krishnalakshmi","objectId":"A1001001A20E08A74322C03420"}
]
```

Now I want to know how it can be split into objects like below in simple java:

```
{"sourcevalue":"KRISHNA@IN.IBM.COM","userIdValue":"Krishna L Pappu - krishnalakshmi","objectId":"A1001001A20E08A74322C03420"}

{"sourcevalue":"KRISHNA@IN.IBM.COM","userIdValue":"Krishna L Pappu - krishnalakshmi","objectId":"A1001001A20E08A74322C03420"}

{"sourcevalue":"KRISHNA@IN.IBM.COM","userIdValue":"Krishna L Pappu - krishnalakshmi","objectId":"A1001001A20E08A74322C03420"}
```

I tried with `split` method its just too clumsy. Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your attempt with `split`. Why is it too clumsy? You should parse this and work with java objects.

Comment: What exactly you need ? it seems that you need to deserialize a json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `@Rabbit` has said, create a deserializer. There are many ways to do this, A sample could be:

```
class SimpleObj {
  private String sourceValue;
  private String userIdValue;
  private String objectId;
  ... getters, and setters ommited

  public static List<SimpleObj> deserializer(String data){
    Type objType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<SimpleObj>>() {}.getType();
    return new ArrayList<>(new Gson().fromJson(data, objType));
  }
}
```

The method `deserializer` which takes in a string needs `Gson()` library to work, so import that to your `classpath`, the method would help you change the incoming string to a list of object, like the one you desire.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks @EtekaChristopher I used gson to serialize and it helped

Answer (score 0):

I used this piece of code to achieve my requirement of deserializing the json object list which I got from Javascript. Hope this helps for requirements of deserializing a list of objects which are retrieved from front end.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static AttributeValue[] jsonToObject (String jsonObj, Class gilClass) {      
    Gson gson = new Gson(); 
    return gson.fromJson(jsonObj, AttributeValue[].class);      

}
```